# How to set width of image which is in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an image with a Webgl hover effect. The effect id working but, I am now trying to set a width for the image which is inside the jQuery,

```
new hoverEffect({
  parent: document.querySelector('.ticket'),
  intensity1: 0.1,
  intensity2: 0.1,
  angle2: Math.PI / 2,
  image1: 'https://source.unsplash.com/Le7_qK9JaLU/500x500',
  image2: 'https://source.unsplash.com/XAqaeyzj3NM/500x500',
  displacementImage: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/robin-dela/hover-effect/b6c6fd26/images/stripe1mul.png?raw=true'
});

.ticket{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: HTML:

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                            <div class="">
                                <div class="ticket">
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

Answer (score 0):

If want to set width the image by using jquery.
just add this line

**Example**

```
$(".img1").css({ 'height': '200px', 'width': '210px' });
```